# Run time exception while using Android Notifcations.

Tags: java, android, notifications

This is my CreateNotification class. Code has been taken from the android page. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Code:

```
package your.notification.manager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.view.View;

public class CreateNotification extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
        CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        final int HELLO_ID = 1;

        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

    }


}
```

Error:

```
05-05 12:51:38.687: E/AndroidRuntime(8629): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentView required: pkg=com.crumbs.main id=0 notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code is working fine..

Just Clean your project and run again.